# Vue3 Composition API Provide/Inject to Router's index.js

Tags: vuejs3, router, composition

I am using a third-party plugin called Lenis for smooth scrolling on my Vue app. I decided to add it to my main.js and utilize "provide". I am using "inject" in components where I can start and stop the scroll smoothing. It works as expected.

What I want to do is to be able to do this in my router's index.js so I can use scrollBehavior().

From this:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve({left: 0, top: 0});
});
```

To this:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // lenis.scrollTo("#anchor");
});
```

When I inject it into my router's index.js, I get undefined for my variable. What's the workaround for this? Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: provide/inject limits the scope of a variable to a component and all of its descendants (in DOM). `router` is an external module, imported in various components, as needed, if needed. But its a module, has nothing to do with DOM, so you can't provide anything to it. Instead, you can import any other module into it. So use import/export instead.

Comment: Hi @tao thanks for your suggestion. I already tried that and I couldn't get it to work for the current instance. Maybe I'm missing something. Could you give me an example of an export/import? For now, I created a global variable and passed the instance to it and this works.

Comment: If you need help you might want to provide a *runnable* [mcve] reproducing the bug. With clear indications on what's the expected behavior. Consider using codesandbox.io or similar. As it stands, I have no idea what you tried, which versions of Vue and lenis you're using, etc... Also, what is it you're trying to achieve? Opening a page and scrolling to a particular achor, after the page has rendered?